# Images not displaying from database and file

Tags: php, mysql, database

i Have set up a site that lets user upload images then those images get displayed back on the home screen. but i hit a wall just now so i got past to letting the user upload an image then that images gets saved to a folder and a database but how can i do it so the image gets displayed on the home screen.

```
 <?php

 // Connect to database

 $errmsg = "";
 if (! @mysql_connect("localhost","alfred1000351","*******")) {
 $errmsg = "Cannot connect to database";
     }
 @mysql_select_db("drp_2cgih5o233");



 $q = <<<CREATE
 create table pix (
 pid int primary key not null auto_increment,
 title text,
 imgdata longblob)
 CREATE;
 @mysql_query($q);

 // Insert any new image into database

  if ($_REQUEST[completed] == 1) {
  // Need to add - check for large upload. Otherwise the code
  // will just duplicate old file ;-)
 // ALSO - note that latest.img must be public write and in a
 // live appliaction should be in another (safe!) directory.
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'],"latest.img");
 $instr = fopen("latest.img","rb");
 $image = addslashes(fread($instr,filesize("latest.img")));
 if (strlen($instr) < 149000) {
 mysql_query ("insert into pix (title, imgdata) values (\"".
 $_REQUEST[whatsit].
 "\", \"".
 $image.
 "\")");
 } else {
 $errmsg = "Too large!";
 }
 }

 // Find out about latest image

  $gotten = @mysql_query("select * from pix order by pid desc limit 1");
  if ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($gotten)) {
  $title = htmlspecialchars($row[title]);
  $bytes = $row[imgdata];
  } else {
  $errmsg = "There is no image in the database yet";
  $title = "no database image available";
  // Put up a picture of our training centre
  $instr = fopen("../wellimg/ctco.jpg","rb");
   $bytes = fread($instr,filesize("../wellimg/ctco.jpg"));
  }

 // If this is the image request, send out the image

if ($_REQUEST[gim] == 1) {
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $bytes;
exit ();
}
?>

<html><head>
<title>Upload an image to a database</title>
<body bgcolor=white><h2>Here's the latest picture</h2>
<font color=red><?= $errmsg ?></font>
<center><img src=?gim=1 width=144><br>
<b><?= $title ?></center>
<hr>
<h2>Please upload a new picture and title</h2>
<form enctype=multipart/form-data method=post>
<input type=hidden name=MAX_FILE_SIZE value=150000>
<input type=hidden name=completed value=1>
Please choose an image to upload: <input type=file name=imagefile><br>
Please enter the title of that picture: <input name=whatsit><br>
then: <input type=submit></form><br>
<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an example/collection from several files, or true implementation?

Comment: sorry I'm new to this but i don't understand what you are saying

Comment: No problem. My question is, is this "real code" you are going to implement, or just an example of code what you have?

Comment: this is the real code I'm trying to implement. Why is the code wrong

Comment: I was just thinking, because it has so many "points to fix", so I wanted to make sure, until replying to it.

Comment: You might try reworking your code so you're not as dependent on squelching errors. Sometimes that can mask some unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my toughts:

1. Do not suppress warnings what you get from DB. They are real, and needed. Remove all @-characters from the front of DB-calls. **If you get any notices, warnings, errors do not suppress them, correct them.**
2. If you are making new code, consider using PDO as DB API, not the old, deprecating PHP MySQL API. It's as easy as MySQL API to use.
3. **You only want try to create table only once**, remove it from code which is executed many times.
4. **You should check if $_REQUEST parameters exists**, and not compare them if they do not. Also you need to **put the parameter names in quotes**, otherwise PHP thinks you are using constants, which you are not. So line `if ($_REQUEST[completed] == 1) {` must be fixed to `if(isset($_REQUEST['completed']) && $_REQUEST['completed'] == 1) {`. Same appies to `whatisit` and `gim` -params.
5. The code `if (strlen($instr) < 149000) {` does not work as intented, you cannot get length of resource. You are probably looking for this functionality: `if (strlen($_FILES['imagefile']['size']) < 149000) {`.
6. Same (as in step 4) with `$row` s you need to **put the literas in quotes**, so fix those lines as: `$title = htmlspecialchars($row['title']); $bytes = $row['imgdata'];`
7. Othewise than that **it should work**. However, it contains DB-security hole, which can lead to compromize your website, so I recommend you NOT to put this to any real site. Just for your own/friends fun.